# My query isn't working. No information is being sent to the table

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin

This is my form:

```
<div id="HomeAgenda">
<div id="HomeAgendaTitle">Agenda</div>
    <div id="HomeAgendaCreate">
        <form method="post" action="#">
            <input type="text" name="HomeAgendaCreateTitle" id="HomeAgendaCreateTitle" placeholder="Subject" /><br>
            <input type="text" name="HomeAgendaCreateLocation" id="HomeAgendaCreateLocation" placeholder="Location" /><br>
            <input type="text" name="HomeAgendaCreateDate" id="HomeAgendaCreateDate" placeholder="Date" />
            <input type="text" name="HomeAgendaCreateTime" id="HomeAgendaCreateTime" placeholder="Time" /><br>
            <input type="text" name="HomeAgendaCreateNotes" id="HomeAgendaCreateNotes" placeholder="Notes" />
            <input type="submit" name="HomeAgendaCreateSubmit" id="HomeAgendaCreateSubmit" value="Save" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my php:

```
<?php
$SetAgendaAppointment = @$_POST['HomeAgendaCreateSubmit'];
$SetAgendaTitle = @$_POST['HomeAgendaCreateTitle'];
$SetAgendaLocation = @$_POST['HomeAgendaCreateLocation'];
$SetAgendaDate = @$_POST['HomeAgendaCreateDate'];
$SetAgendaTime = @$_POST['HomeAgendaCreateTime'];
$SetAgendaNotes = @$_POST['HomeAgendaCreateNotes'];
if($SetAgendaAppointment) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO agenda VALUES('$SetAgendaTitle','$SetAgendaLocation','$SetAgendaDate','$SetAgendaTime','$SetAgendaNotes','$user_id')");
}
?>
```

This is my database connecting code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","250317") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("bakpakk");
?>
```

On my page after i submit the information from the form, nothing happens. When i check the agenda table, nothing is submitted and phpmyadmin returns zero rows in the table. I can't seem to figure out why? After submitting data no more data is entered into the table if there's any data already in the table.Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You're wide open for SQL injections.

Comment: Also, is that ALL of the PHP code? Did you connect to the database previously, etc.

Comment: yes i have connected to the database, there's a separate file that connects this to the database, and I don't really know what SQL injections are :/

Comment: Are you checking for mysql errors?  You're not specifying the columns to insert, so if the number of parameters doesn't match the number of columns in the table, the insert will fail.

Comment: and I have a lot of other PHP code for other things i'm trying to accomplish with this: users, settings, notes, etc.

Comment: Remove all the @ symbols from your code they are masking any errors that could be occuring. As was previously commented - where is your database connection code?

Comment: I checked the columns, and the number of items i'm inserting into the table at any time is always 6 columns which is the number of columns my 'agenda' table has, invariably.

Comment: Are you loading them in the same order as they appear in the database. Better to use a `INSERT x,y,z VALUES( $x, $y , $z )` syntax if you are not sure.

Comment: All of the errors were missing indexes which was just a warning that didn't affect the functions of the site, i have other code for registration that had the same errors and I masked the errors there too, but the registration wasn't affected.

Comment: Also, yes they are, in fact, in the same order as in the table, so I don't understand what's wrong :/

Comment: Please, if you found a solution, write an _answer_.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up in my original dummy values, I put an apostrophe in one of the inputs and it messed up the query

Comment: New Problem btw, if you read the bottom of my question nothing new is being added to the table if there's any data already in the table

Comment: @user2241378 Well you are going to have to show your PHP code that does the database maintenance and retrieval

Comment: what database maintenance?

Comment: fixed again, turns out i accidentally set the user_id section in the table to the primary key and since there can't be duplicates of that it wasn't processing

Comment: @user2241378 Do you man you dont get more than one row in the table OR that the data in the row does not change?

Comment: The data in that row doesn't change and no more rows can be added after that but it's fixed now

Comment: @user2241378 Thats what I was expecting you to say!!!

Comment: If it's answered, you should be marking one of the answers accepted, not adding an (ANSWERED) label onto your question title.

Comment: You should use prepared statements with PDO or MySQLi instead of mysql_ functions. SQL injections, as stated, are currently a risk with this code. If you don't switch at least use something like mysql_real_escape_string to sanitize the user input before being used in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Add some error trapping code, so you can see if something has gone wrong with the query.

```
if($SetAgendaAppointment) {
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO agenda  VALUES('$SetAgendaTitle','$SetAgendaLocation','$SetAgendaDate','$SetAgendaTime','$SetAgendaNotes','$user_id')";
    //ensure your creating the proper statement
    var_dump($SQL);
    $result = mysql_query($SQL); 

    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

}
```

Comment: Also not working, it takes me to a blank page and inserts nothing into the table

Comment: @user2241378 Are you getting any information from the php error log?

Comment: yes, it said i'm using improper syntax, and then i looked at the code just now and it turns out that when i entered some values into the form i included an apostrophe in one of the inputs so that was taken as a single quote and since it wasn't closed the entire query was broken... I just have to remove all the punctuation before entering it into the query

Comment: @user2241378 Always check the error log first, when developing make sure you have `display_errors = On` in the php.ini file.

Comment: @user2241378: So, it's because you didn't sanitize your inputs. Why did you not sanitize your inputs?

Comment: New Problem btw, if you read the bottom of my question nothing new is being added to the table if there's any data already in the table

Answer (score -1):

```
//ensure you're getting your variables
vardump($_POST);
if($SetAgendaAppointment) {
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO agenda VALUES('$SetAgendaTitle','$SetAgendaLocation','$SetAgendaDate','$SetAgendaTime','$SetAgendaNotes','$user_id')";
    //ensure you're creating the proper statement
    var_dump($SQL);
    mysql_query($SQL); // what are you doing with this? you're just running it and not saving it to a var?
}
```

Comment: This isn't working, i tried putting the string into a variable and then running the query but it doesn't work :/

Comment: Its not supposed to just work, its supposed to help you diagnose what's going wrong. Read the comments I put in the code. Essentially your not doing anything with your query once you've run it.

Comment: -1: Why would you want to store the result of an `INSERT` into a variable? There isn't any result. It's a statement, not a query. There is no data to return. Also, stop writing "your" instead of "you're", please!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh yes there is. If the query failes for whatever reason the result of mysql_query is set to `FALSE`. Very useful to know while you are testing and put a value into the screen with an apostrophe in it and have been too lazy to sanitize the values coming from the page!

Comment: New Problem btw, if you read the bottom of my question nothing new is being added to the table if there's any data already in the table

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Sure, do some error checking on the return type, but by "saving it to a var" it sounded like you wanted to store it over the long term, which for anything but a recordset is pointless. Traditionally you would stick your `mysql_query` call directly inside an `if` clause; no need for any variables.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yup, maybe. But I was just keeping it simple for someone who is obviously just learning.